# <DIV> overlaying other Elements

Tags: html, treeview, overlay

I have a treeview which when visible takes too much space on the web page. Hence the user is asked to click a button to make this visible :) But the issue here is that when that treeview ( located within a  element ) is made visible it MOVES the other elements down but i would prefer if it OVERLAYS ( something like what happens when we click a dropdown ) :P

Any Pointers or any other possible soltions are much Appreciated.

Thank You :P

PS : It would be much better if the solution does NOT involve flash or SilverLight controls :P as it would be too much load for just one Control !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS to either position the element absolutely or float it, both of which remove it from the page flow.

Here is what the MDC says about the `float` property (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Float)):

> The float property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Here is what the MDC says about the `position: absolute` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Values)):

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the initial containing block.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of the element to Absolute in your CSS

Position: absolute;

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp